# groupby on Column name and create new column with value using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am not getting the logic, how can I achieve it. Refer the below table image, I want to grouping on **TRACE** column and if there is value *no_emp_id* in **RESOLVED_QUERY** than create new column with value *no_emp_id*.
**Demo Table 1**

[image: Demo Table]

I tried to iterate the row but not getting proper result, have a look what I am getting, **My Result**
[image: My Result]

Have a look on expected result. **Expected result**

[image: Expected result]

Please help me out to solve this task.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can group by with `.unique()` function (in the second step) to find if a `'trace'` include any value (ex. `'no_emp_id'`)

example:

##### 1.initialization dummy db to example

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
  'trace':['1a223b','2b223b','3a33c','2b223b','1a223b','3a33c','3a33c'],
  'resolved_query':['no_emp_id','TELE_WEL','TELE_WEL','good','TELE_WEL','no_emp_id','no_emp_id']
})
>>> df
    trace resolved_query
0  1a223b      no_emp_id
1  2b223b       TELE_WEL
2   3a33c       TELE_WEL
3  2b223b           good
4  1a223b       TELE_WEL
5   3a33c      no_emp_id
6   3a33c      no_emp_id
```

##### 2.setting a controller df to control traces if any trace include `'no_emp_id'`

this df helps us to find which `'trace'` include what

```py
>>> controller_df = df.groupby('trace')['resolved_query'].unique().reset_index().copy()
>>> controller_df
    trace         resolved_query
0  1a223b  [no_emp_id, TELE_WEL]
1  2b223b       [TELE_WEL, good]
2   3a33c  [TELE_WEL, no_emp_id]
```

##### 3.creating new column which is `'command'` with include desired_value (`'no_emp_id'`)

in this step , we just quick check each `'trace'` with our `controller_df`, if a `'trace'` include our desired value, just we add to new column

```py
>>> desired_value = 'no_emp_id'
>>> df['command'] = df['trace'].apply(lambda x: desired_value if (desired_value in controller_df[controller_df['trace']==x]['resolved_query'].iloc[0]) else None)
>>> df.sort_values('trace')

    trace resolved_query    command
0  1a223b      no_emp_id  no_emp_id
4  1a223b       TELE_WEL  no_emp_id
1  2b223b       TELE_WEL       None
3  2b223b           good       None
2   3a33c       TELE_WEL  no_emp_id
5   3a33c      no_emp_id  no_emp_id
6   3a33c      no_emp_id  no_emp_id
```

as we see, `'2b223b'` is not match any `'no_emp_id'` in the `'resolved_query'` so we didnt add it to `'command'` column